# Magento 2: Moving the logo of my storefront to the center

Tags: magento2

How can I move the logo of my storefront to the center by using the move tag in the layout default.xml file?

Comment: are u trying on luma theme?

Comment: can you please share with me your website URL

Comment: @Amit Bera: Actually on custom_theme but inheriting luma theme.

Answer (score 0):

> I did  on luma theme

Hope this help you !   `.logo` is your **logo  wrapper class**.

```
.logo {
        margin: -8px auto @indent__m 0;
         margin-left: 450px;
```

for custom theme find class  just find by inspecting on browser

Comment: It's issue in responsive layout

Answer (score 0):

The logo image inside luma theme is wrapped inside `<strong>` element with class `.logo` , add this style code inside your css file to make the logo align center horizontally:

```
.logo {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

Comment: It's issue in responsive layout

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
.logo {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: none;
}
.logo img {
    max-height: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This pushes the left search and minicart icon to the bottom.